# How do I break on debug output in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I keep getting this message `Rect: identifier "posPt" is undefined` hundreds of times in my debug output, yet, I can't find it in the code I'm debugging.  So I tried to break whenever one of the following functions are called: `_CrtDbgReport`, `_CrtDbgReportV`, `_CrtDbgReportW`, and `_CrtDbgReportWV`, which I found by drilling down through the TRACE code.  I also found `_CrtDbgReportT` and `_CrtDbgReportTV` as well, but they don't seem to have any linkage as I couldn't set a breakpoint on them.

In any case, it still wouldn't break, so either these are not being called and some other similar function is, or the debugger isn't getting all instances of the linkages.

So, my question is how do I find out where the output is being generated?

**EDIT:** The application is C++ native code with several DLLs linked in.

Comment: `OutputDebugString` is ultimately responsible; it may have been called directly by the code. Add a breakpoint to that function. Brace yourself for false positives.

Comment: @CodyGray, `OutputDebugString` is not being recognised as a linked symbol.  Found `OutputDebugStringW` and `OutputDebugStringA`, but still doesn't break on them.

Answer (score 0):

This was a while ago, and I do not know if I ever found the issue.  However, looking back at this, it may have been caused by a breakpoint that had an Action to log to the output window, either referencing a variable that doesn't exist anymore, or the breakpoint being moved due to lines being added/removed by a source control programme, moving the variable out of scope.

Given the output `Rect: identifier "posPt" is undefined`, the action would have read as `Rect: {posPt}`.